# Different page templates for pages

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, templates

I need to create 2 templates for pages: "with sidebar" and "without sidebar".

I need to show sidebar for certain pages and hide it for others.
This behavior should be configured thru options and not thru code.

How can I make it in Joomla 3.4.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a simple thing to do. In your template's index.php add the following and change `position-8` to whatever position in the sidebar.

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-8')) : ?>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="xhtml" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically, what this does is, it detects if there are any modules assigned to `position-8` and will display the sidebar **only** if there are.

You may have multiple positions inside the sidebar, so you can also use:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-8') && $this->countModules('position-9')): ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Pages "with sidebar" and "without sidebar" have different page structure (different element wrappers) and probably adding module to position and checking if there are any modules for current page is not best choice for my case. Is there way to create 2 different page templates and set one or another for certain pages?

Comment: Ahh ok. Is your template a custom template or did you download it?

Comment: I made custom template from scratch using Joomla docs.

Comment: I got it. I will change the wrapper classes using same php condition you provided. And sidebar will be hidden if there is no modules on that position. IMHO it looks pretty tricky but it works for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to duplicate your template from Template Manager and do the modifications (no sidebar) to the new one without messing with the original one.

Then go to your menu and edit the menu item of your choice by selecting from "Template Style" list the duplicated (no sidebar) template.